# Ruby SSL communication

Tags: ruby, ssl

I am unable to find an SSL implementation for Ruby.

Part of my project requires a secure communication link between the Server and Client, and I was hoping to use SSL for this in order to create a secure session.

Thanks

Comment: Please give us a little more to go on, are you writing a client- or server-side app? The [HTTPClient gem](http://rubydoc.info/gems/httpclient/2.2.4/HTTPClient/SSLConfig) has OpenSSL support

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, where did you even see rails in this question?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Ruby 1.9.x you could try the [OpenSSL](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

simply use the [certified](https://github.com/stevegraham/certified) gem.

```
gem install certified.
```

this gem will install ca cert for ssl. using libssl could be an option but as far I know it makes problem with ruby 1.9.1.